# React: Why is it skipping over my "fetch" function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

I am a bit new to React and am trying to have data from MySQL print in my console, but it seems not to print what I want it to print.

```js
componentDidMount(){
    console.log('Hi')
    fetch('http://localhost:6000/test')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((users) => console.log('This is your data'))
    console.log('Hi')
  }
```

Initially, I had ".then((users) => console.log('This is your data', users))", but because it didn't print out, I removed "users" to just test the string.

In my console, it prints Hi, a newline, and Hi again. Because it shows this, I'm assuming it skips over my fetch statement as it doesn't print "This is your data" either. Am I thinking the right way? Is there a reason "This is your data" doesn't print as well?
Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: `fetch()` is asynchronous, so code before and after it will run before code inside both `.then()` blocks executes. Its not skipping `fetch()`, chain a `catch` block at the end of the promise chain to make sure promise is not being rejected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's isn't skipping over the fetch, this is just how asynchronous functions and Promises work in javascript .

`fetch` returns a promise and is asynchronous, so when execution is plowing through `componentDidMount` it does the first log, queues up the `fetch` (which resolves later), then does the second log. You'll see the final "this is your data" log when the `fetch` promise chain resolves.

If you want to really see the logs in order then you may want to use an `async` function.

```
async componentDidMount(){
  console.log('Hi')
  await fetch('http://localhost:6000/test') // <-- pause execution and wait for promise to resolve before continuing
    .then((response) => response.json())
    .then((users) => console.log('This is your data'))
  console.log('Hi')
}
```

Check if the fetch was successful and handle rejected Promises

```
async componentDidMount(){
  console.log('Hi')
  await fetch('http://localhost:6000/test')
    .then((response) => {
      if (!response.ok) { // <-- check the ok status
        throw new Error('Response not ok');
      }
      return response.json();
    })
    .then((users) => console.log('This is your data'))
    .catch(err => console.error(err)); // <-- log thrown errors
  console.log('Hi')
}
```

Comment: Oh that makes a lot of sense! How do you know when the promise is resolved or rejected? Would it take a long time? I implemented your suggestion and it might be hanging?

Comment: @webdesignnoob Oh, yeah, I didn't entirely read your issue. Yes, seems like the sad path is happening. `fetch` only rejects on cancelled requests and network errors, otherwise it returns a resolved promise. [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch). For this reason you need to test `response.ok` before returning `response.json()` ([Check if successful](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#Checking_that_the_fetch_was_successful)). Add a `.catch(console.log)` to the end of the chain to see what may be occurring.

Comment: Ah, I see! Thank you for explaining, it makes more sense now.